# js gallery not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, gallery, thumbnails

This js gallery works fine in IE9, FF, Safari etc, but not in IE8. When the thumbs are clicked nothing happens on the page.

Does anyone know why?

My page is located [here](http://www.test25.net/gems/jQueryUI/myDesign/combiner-page03.html)

HTML (cut down version):

```
        <div id="strandScroll">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="images/IMG_8720_.jpg" class="thumbnailStrand"><img src="images/IMG_8720_small.jpg" 
            alt="Image 1" border="0"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/IMG_9112.jpg" class="thumbnailStrand"><img src="images/IMG_9112_small.jpg" 
            alt="Thumbnail 2" border="0"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="claspScroll">
        <ul>  
        <li><a href="images/IMG_8626.png" class="thumbnailClasp"><img src="images/IMG_8626.png" 
            alt="Image 1" border="0"/></a> </li>          
        <li><a href="images/IMG_8577.png" class="thumbnailClasp"><img src="images/IMG_8577.png" 
            alt="Thumbnail 2" border="0"/></a></li>       
        </ul>
        <div>

        <div id="combinedStrand">
        <img src="images/IMG_8720_.jpg" max-width 100% alt="Main Image" id="mainImageStrand" class="combinedStrandImage"/>
        </div>

        <div id="combinedClasp">
        <img src="images/IMG_8577.png" alt="Main ImageClasp" id="mainImageClasp" class="combinedClasp"/>
        </div>
```

js:

```
            $(function() {
                $('.thumbnailStrand').live('click', function() {
                    $('#mainImageStrand').hide();
                    $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'url(ajax-loader.gif)');
                    $('<img />').attr('src', this.href).load(function() {
                          $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
                          $('#mainImageStrand').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).fadeIn();
                    });
                    return false;
              });
             $('.thumbnailClasp').live('click', function() {
                    $('#mainImageClasp').hide();
                    $('#imageWrapClasp').css('background-image', 'url(ajax-loader.gif)');
                    $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
                          $('#imageWrapClasp').css('background-image', 'none');
                          $('#mainImageClasp').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).fadeIn();
                    });
                    return false;

            $(".thumbnail").click(function() {

        $("#mainImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));   
                        });
              });

        });
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

 Use .on() to attach event handlers. http://api.jquery.com/live/

As you're loading jQuery 1.7.1 this may be the issue.

Try changing your .live() to .on()

Comment: No, this did not solve my issue I'm afraid. But I will take your advice and change it to .on(). Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your `load` event is never being fired.

This is possibly an intended (at the time) optimisation, since it's kind of pointless to load an image that hasn't been added to the DOM yet.

I recommend not screwing around with jQuery and just do it the old-fashioned way:

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = this.href;
i.onload = function() {
    $('#imageWrapClasp').css blah blah blah
    more blah here
}
```

Comment: its funny that you use jQuery in this solution. :)

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb Kolink, but where exactly should I add this js?

Comment: Use it instead of the current `<img/>` line thingy. @Michael: I know, I couldn't be bothered to change the rest. :p

Comment: I keeg getting syntax errors when I try put this in :( It looks like this now can you tell me what I am doing wrong?     $(function() {
          $('.thumbnailStrand').on('click', function() {
                $('#mainImageStrand').hide();
                $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'url(ajax-loader.gif)');
     var i = new Image(); i.src = this.href; i.onload = function() {
                      $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
                      $('#mainImageStrand').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).fadeIn();
                });
                return false;

Comment: that got rid of the syntax errors ok, but doesn't fix the IE8 issue :( Any other ideas why this is happening?